# Only allow positive numbers with only one decimal in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new on Stack overflow so please forgive me If I am wrong anywhere. I am stuck with the problem in Angular 6, I have few input fields of type number and text and I want to prevent users from entering any character other than '.' (dot) and only enter positive numbers with a single dot for eg.  "1.22" and not "1..2." or "-1.12" or "-111".

I have tried (keyup), (keypress) and (keydown) but each of them works really confusing for me. Please advice if there is any directive or any solution. 
in html

```
 <input type="number"(keyup)="numberOnlyWithDecimal($event,xyz)" name="weight [(ngModel)]="xyz" min="0" step="0.1">
```

in .ts

```
public textlength=0;


numberOnlyWithDecimal(event, text): boolean {

var regex = /^\d+(\.\d+)?$/;
const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
var text2 = text + ''
var test = text2.split(".")
if (text2) {  
  this.textlength = test.length-1 ;
}
if(text == null && charCode == 46){
  return false;
}

if (charCode != 46 && charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
  return false;
}
if (!regex.test(charCode)) {
  return false
}
if (charCode === 46 && this.textlength ===1 ) {
  return false
}
return true;
```

}

Comment: Right mouse click and select "paste" will bypass any attempts to limit when keys a user can press.

Comment: Actually pasting is not the issue in the project I am working. I just want that user can only enter positive values with maximum one dot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after loads of brainstorming, I have found a working solution for me. I would like to thanks all for helping me, you guys are savior.

I have used @yanky_cranky code and modified it a little bit and it worked for both number and text input type. Here is the code.

```
<input type="number" name="weight" appNumbersOnly [(ngModel)]="xyz"/>
```

Directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
    selector: '[appNumbersOnly]'
  })



export class NumbersOnlyDirective {
    public text;

    private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*){0,1}$/g);
    private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab'];

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }
    @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
      if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
        return;
      }
      const current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
      const next: string = current.concat(event.key);

      if(next.includes('.')){
        if(this.text == next){
          event.preventDefault();
        }
        this.text= next;
      }
      if ((next && !String(next).match(this.regex))) {  
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Here you go, complete working solution for you :

1) Directive

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[appNumbersOnly]'
})
export class NumbersOnlyDirective {

  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^-?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*){0,1}$/g);
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab'];

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
      return;
    }
    const current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
    const next: string = current.concat(event.key);
    if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
      event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
}
```

2) Usage in html

```
<input type="text" name="weight" appNumbersOnly [(ngModel)]="xyz"  />
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xydqra) here for reference

Comment: @yanky_carnky Thanks for the solution. It is working perfectly fine in stackblitz but for some reason, in my project, I can input two consecutive decimals. this is the HTML code  `<input type="number"  appNumbersOnly name="weight" [(ngModel)]="anthropometry.body_measurements.weight.measure (ngModelChange)="onParamsChange($event)" min="0" step="0.1">`

Comment: can you share your stackblitz

Comment: fixed (y) please check, now you no need to address type as number make it text instead

Comment: yes I now can see it working with type="text" but the project required to have a type number because of the upper and lower buttons in input. Is there any way to achieve this in type="number"?

Comment: @ShubhamDubey hide it using css

Answer (score 1):

you can create your custom directive

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[appTwoDigitDecimaNumber]'
})

export class TwoDigitDecimaNumberDirective {
  private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^\d*\.?\d{0,2}$/g);
  private specialKeys: Array<string> = ['Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home', '-'];

  @Input('appTwoDigitDecimaNumber') decimal:any;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
  }
  @HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])

  onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
    if(this.decimal){  
      if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
        return;
      }
      let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
      let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
      if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }else{
      const charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
      if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 105)) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
      return;
    }
  }
```

**Usage**

```
<input type="text" [appTwoDigitDecimaNumber]="true">
```

I hope it will help you a lot.

Note : you can use it any `number` type field where you want use just add `[appTwoDigitDecimaNumber]="true"` if you dont want to use then add `[appTwoDigitDecimaNumber]="false"`.
Bacause i have use these directive in dynamic forms that why i have set it base on `true` or `false`.
You can use it in `Dynamic form` also

Comment: I am really thankful for your help, but  the input is accepting multiple decimals and also negative numbers and even I can type multiple minus sign whereas user must not allowed to enter any negative value or minus sign and also no multiple dots.

Comment: You just need to change here regex pattern

Comment: Sorry but I don't have much knowledge about the regex pattern.