# Angular way to stop negative values from being entered in input type number (on copy-paste & increase, decrease) also

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angularjs, angular

my requirement is in an angular project i'm taking number input in a form like this

`<input type="number" #input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="dataItem.quantity"`

i should not allow user to enter negative values even from copy-paste or through increase / decrease button of input type number or thought keyboard.

how can we acheive this, i have seen some directives, there they are taking input as 'text', my case is it should be "input type number" only.

It should allow decimals also.

Please Help me.

Comment: This will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372067/is-there-any-way-to-prevent-input-type-number-getting-negative-values

Comment: [Only allow positive numbers with only one decimal in Angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57151147)

Comment: @SivakumarTadisetti Thanks, my requirement is like not event to entered in input, without validations support, entry also should not happen...

Comment: Hi Shaik, I have added a solution.. Please check and let me know whether that solve your problem..

Comment: Hello @aks44, usefull, when i decrease value when it is 0 (zero), showing value as 1, it should show 0 only

Comment: Use input type="text"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like below

HTML:

```
<input type="number" min="0" (input)="checkValue($event)">
```

TS:

```
checkValue(event) {
  if (event.target.value < 0) {
    event.target.value = 0;
  }
}
```

You can use `(keyup)` too

**Update:**

> In the Angular way, you can create a pipe. Working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hv2rmd)

In the HTML:

```
<input type="number" min="0" [ngModel]="testValue | nonegativevalue" (ngModelChange)="testValue=$event">
```

**nonegativevaluepipe**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'nonegativevalue'})
export class NoNegativeValue implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number): number {
    if(value < 0) {
      value = 0;
      return value;
    }
    return value;
  }
}
```

> If you use reactive form, then check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-wbphcc)

Comment: In reactive forms approach how we use this pipe ?  @Sivakumar Tadisetti

Comment: @ShaikHabeeb updated my answer, check below line of the answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try this..

```
<input type="number" min="0" #input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="dataItem.quantity" 
oninput="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');">
```

Comment: if `input type='text'` then we don't see the increase and decrease buttons in the text box

Comment: try type="number" min="0"

Answer (score 0):

if you are using template driven approach, you can use this pattern :             pattern="^[1-9]+[0-9]*$"
on template where you have defined your field (html file). this is quick and easy